# Why is textAlign or align not working in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have tried doing it through my App.css file, then I tried inline styling but it still will not align the button in the center of the screen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css'

class Body extends Component {
    btn = {
        
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button style={{textAlign:'center'}}>Get Started</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Body;
```

Comment: Can you try giving ```style={{textAlign:'center'}}``` to the ```div``` element and **not** for ```button``` ??

Comment: Yes!! It worked. Thank you so much. Do you happen to know why this works over putting it in the button tag?

Comment: @Caleb, I have posted the reason for the change in below answer and please look into it and kindly accept if it resolves your issue..

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, where in-line styling would not work when using a 'semantic-ui-react' Header component.
But after wrapping the Header component inside a  and applying the `textAlign: 'center'` styling on the  it worked.